# PHP OOP, using a "clean" child constructor

Tags: php, oop

I have a question about a simple PHP class extend. When I have this parent class:

```
<?php
class Parent
{
    protected $_args;

    public function __construct($args)
    {
        $this->_args = $args;
    }
}
?>
```

Which I want to extend using:

```
<?php
class Child extends Parent
{
    public function __construct($args)
    {
        parent::__construct($args);

        /* Child constructor stuff goes here. */
    }
}
?>
```

Im calling this child class using:

```
new Child($args);
```

This all works without any problem, but the the question is: Is is possible to have a "clean" constructor in the child, without having to pass all the constructor parameters to the parent? I see the Kohana framework uses this technique but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "clean" child constructor...

Comment: I want to call the parents constructor from the child, but I dont want to pass all the arguments to the parent constructor again.

Answer (score 6):

You can define an `init()` method that is called from the parent constructor.

```
class Parent
{
    protected $_args;

    public function __construct($args)
    {
        $this->_args = $args;

        $this->init();
    }

    protected function init() {}
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    protected function init()
    {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, seems like its working fine, thanks! Is this a common way to achieve this?

Comment: By making the parent __construct "final", I'm now preventing constructor overriding from the child. Might come in handy for others.

Comment: Be aware that you might want to call parent::init() in your Child's init() as well

Comment: Indeed, figured that out myself, works perfectly fine now thanks for the input.

Comment: I use this method but test for the existence of the `init()` function before calling it in case I subclass the `Parent` class again and don't need any additional initialisation code.

Comment: That's why you have the empty init() method in the parent class. That way, if the child doesn't override it, it does nothing.